# (S)FTP that works similar to SVN (Uploading changed files)

Tags: laravel, macos, svn, ftp, sftp

Not sure if something like this exists, but my searches thus far have come up empty.

Basically all I want to do is be able to monitor a local directory for changes and upload only those files to a server via (S)FTP.

I am currently developing a web app using Laravel. Laravel has a fairly comprehensive directory structure, and it can be difficult to remember what all files you changed. It'd be nice if there were software that kept track of changes for you, and then allowed you to upload only those files, once changes are detected.

Surely I can't be alone in wanting this functionality. Right?... right?

Comment: Just sounds like you should use version control to me, tag it when you are ready to deploy and then either upload the ZIP with SFTP or by pulling the git repository directly onto the server.

Comment: That's rsync if I recall correctly

Answer (score 0):

- [FTP Synchronizer](https://www.ftpsynchronizer.com/ftp-sync.php) or [FTPSync](https://www.cyberkiko.com/page/ftpsync/) without any additional layers
- Any VCS of choice with hooks feature (you'll need post-commit hook, which have to write by hand) or "more specific" variations of this choice (known to me)

  - [How to keep Subversion and a remote server (via FTP) in sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922587/how-to-keep-subversion-and-a-remote-server-via-ftp-in-sync)
  - [Sync FTP to SVN](https://superuser.com/questions/520263/sync-ftp-to-svn)
  - Mercurial + [hgftp extension](https://bitbucket.org/misery/hgftp) (my personal choice)